# Trying to get property 'title' of non-object (View: /home/sporaylq/public_html/core/resources/views/singlepage.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel-5

> Trying to get property 'title' of non-object (View:
>   /home/sporaylq/public_html/core/resources/views/singlepage.blade.php)

```
<?php $__env->startSection('title',$page->title); ?>

@section('content')
<div class="main main-raised">
 <div class="container">
     <div class="section section-text">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
           <h3 class="title"><?php echo e($page->title); ?></h3>
            <p>Last Update <?php echo e($page->updated_at->diffForHumans()); ?></p>
             <br>
              <?php echo $page->content; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's in `$page`? It is nowhere getting defined in the code you posted.

Comment: I have very little knowledge

Comment: Could you show the controller that returns the view? `view('singlepage')`?